# Problem of C++ compilation with Expression()

Tags: python, c++, fenics

I am a beginner in fenics and I am trying to resolve Poisson equation with a boundary condition which is a Perlin noise generated by `opensimplex`, a Python library.

I'm trying to define f, the boundary condition by `Expression()`.

I tried `Expression('function(x[0],x[1],x[2])')` where `function (x,y,z)=opensimplex.tmp.noise3d(x,y,z))`. However, as this opensimplex function is not managed by C++, I got a compilation error; `Compilation failed!`.

Is there any solution to overcome this  error ?

Comment: Show the code and the compilation error please.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when starting to work with transient flows in FEniCS. 
Defining a subclass for UserExpression, before defining your variational form should enable the compilation.

```py
    from dolfin import *
    parameters["reorder_dofs_serial"] = True

### (Here you add your domain generation and FunctionSpace definition)

    class Expression(SubDomain):
      def inside(self,a,on_boundary):
         return (x[0]) and (x[1]) and (x[2]) and on_boundary

    f=MyExpression(2.0)
    print(assemble(f*dx(domain=UnitIntervalMesh(1))))
```

If this still doesn't enable compilation, please attach the relevant portions of your code, and we can try to work through them.

If you have a fixed dimension order (e.g. 2-D), you might also have to add this after reordering dofs:

```
parameters["form_compiler"]["quadrature_degree"]=2
```

Good luck!